# transcluded component cannot access its parent required controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent component that is using transclude functionality. In its transcluded part as a default there is the child component:

```
     export class ParentController {

               // some logic here
            }

            angular.module('dmp').component('parentObject', {
                bindings: {

                },
                controller: ParentController,
                transclude: true,
                templateUrl: 'test/parent.html'
            });
    }



    export class ChildController {



    }

    angular.module('dmp').component('childObject', {
        bindings: {

        },
        require: {
            parentCtrl: '^parentObject'
        },
        controller: ChildController,
        templateUrl: 'test/child.html'
    });
}
```

index.html:

```
<parent-object>

</parent-object>
```

parent.html

```
<div ng-transclude>
     <child-object></child-object>
</div>
```

Note that `<child-object>` is in the transclude part of parent object

I get the following error:

```
Controller 'parentObject', required by directive 'childObject', can't be found!
```

if I make it like this it works as expected but this is not my case.

```
<parent-object>
    <child-object></child-object>
</parent-object>
```

Thanks

EDIT related to gyc comment.

If I understood correctly I can remove the `<div ng-transclude>` part and just use the child object without transclusion. This is ok but I want later on to say:

```
<parent-object>
   <some-other-object></some-other-object>
</parent-Object>
```

And then the `<child-object>` will be replaced by the `<some-other-object>`. If I do not use transclusion this will not happen and the `<child-object>` will remain.

Comment: Can you reproduce your error in a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: Never been good at creating snippets - I tried but  failed as I am using typescript and couldn't make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

try change this in the `childObject` definition

```
require: {
    parentController: '^parentObject'
}
```

maybe `parentCtrl` is not a defined alias for `parentController`

Comment: No, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

camelcased components are dash delimited as dom-elements, so it shoud look like this:

```
angular.module('dmp').component('childObject', {
    bindings: {

    },
    require: {
        parentCtrl: '^parent-object'
    },
    controller: ChildController,
    templateUrl: 'test/child.html'
});
```